# [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The"key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey

Tags: javascript, axios

got the error on the title when executing the function executeNewOrder, it seems to be something about the format of the signature, maybe something about the string or type, could anyone help?

```
import axios from "axios";
import crypto from "crypto";

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
const apiSecret = process.env.API_SECRET;
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL;

export async function executeNewOrder(symbol, quantity, side, price) {
  const data = {
    symbol,
    quantity,
    side,
    price,
    type: "LIMIT",
    timeInForce: "GTC",
  };

  const timeStamp = Date.now();
  const recvWindow = 50000;
  // limite de tempo para executar ordem

  const signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", apiSecret).update(
    `${new URLSearchParams({
      ...data,
      timeStamp,
      recvWindow,
    }).toString()}`.digest("hex")
  );

  const newData = { ...data, timeStamp, recvWindow, signature };
  const qs = `?${new URLSearchParams(newData).toString()}`;

  const result = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `${apiUrl}/v3/order${qs}`,
    headers: { " X-MBX-APIKEY": apiKey },
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: from the code you posted, it's likely complaining about the value of `apiSecret` in `crypto.createHmac("sha256", apiSecret)` ... troubleshooting hint ... `console.log(typeof apiSecret)` to see what type it is

Comment: how is `API_SECRET` being set in the environment? An actual environment value, or are you using `dotenv`?

Comment: just checked and its really returning undenifed (apiSecret), good idea trying a typeof. My API_KEY and other are all set in .env file!!!

Comment: omg, think i forgot to import on the file

Comment: yeah!!! i forgot to import and config dotenv, my bad guys, thank u so much, thats my first job alone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm install dotenv
```

And insert the following code between the 'crypto import' statement and the 'const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY' declaration.

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
```

I hope I've helped!

Comment: If you're using NodeJS version 20.6 or greater, you can also use the flag --env-file .env on your dev/build script within package.json because, starting from this version, NodeJS no longer requires dotenv to load environment variables.